# Organizing Actionscript project

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, project-organization, file-organization

I'm learning different programing languages for more than 4 years, but I have never thought about how to organize stuff, because in php its more easier than flash. Now I need to make a radio player, but I dont know how to organize the stuff, to not to lost myself. Please giv me advice what classes should I make and what to do and not to do in main class for this project.

Thank you in advance.

Sorry for taking your spare time.

Raimonds,
Latvia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Are there best practices for (Java) package organisation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226282/are-there-best-practices-for-java-package-organisation)
Check the accepted reply. It is pretty much identical to AS3 best practices.

Comment: I had common sense about that and I have read some articles about this, but the problem is I cant think of ovn names. Maybe you can give example for this radio player app, so I have real example what classes should there be and what to do or not to do in main class? Thanks

Comment: Well you could have something like a VisualPlayer (buttons and such), Player (plays given file, seeks to certain point, etc), MusicLoader (loads music from wherever). You will probably use more classes. I don't know what an radio player app is exactly but these would be the basis of what I could think.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to not to screw up, or lost my self in code.

Comment: A good start is to think of the separation of visual components and data components and separate those into packages.

Answer (score 3):

A wide range of MVC frameworks are available to ensure a solid architecture :

- [Cairngorm](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/cairngorm/Cairngorm) : backed by Adobe, the one you're supposed to use with Flex/MXML
- [Robotlegs](http://www.robotlegs.org/) : a lightweight open-source alternative
- [PureMVC](http://puremvc.org/) : another open-source alternative

Others players are [Swiz](http://swizframework.org/), [Mate](http://mate.asfusion.com/), [Parsley](http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley/)

For a project like yours, Robotlegs is the perfect tool for the job.