# Union all Controllers in one packages will this decrease Spring Component Scanning time?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller

Hi I have over 30 controllers in **My Spring Rest** application and every controller is in a separate package.

```
├───account
│      AccountController.java
│
├───commons
│       AbstractController.java
│
├───offering
│       OfferingController.java
│
│
├───payment
│       PaymentController.java
│
├───paymentProfiles
│       ProfileController.java
│
├───product
│       ProductController.java
│
│
├───publication
│       PublicationController.java
│
│
├───transaction
│       TransactionController.java
```

Is it a good idea to make a new package *controllers*  and put all of them in this location will this increase Spring Package Scanning.

Comment: But is it a good practice in my case?

Comment: When you think about it it's the [exact *opposite* of what makes sense](https://twitter.com/jessitron/status/578894315277000705). Interesting read: http://olivergierke.de/2013/01/whoops-where-did-my-architecture-go/ and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is clearly addressed by ***Effective Java Item 55: Optimize Judiciously***. Most pointedly, Mr Blog says:

> Don’t sacrifice sound architectural principles for performance. Strive to write
>   good programs rather than fast ones

Your endeavored optimization will only yield a couple of milliseconds if any and that at loading time (where it is less valuable).

**Structure your packages with structural consideration rather than performance considerations**. If you are looking for best practices, apply generic package organisation practices like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226282/are-there-best-practices-for-java-package-organisation).

Comment: OK if a have sub packages and another classes put all in one package is obvious bad idea. But in my case I think even when they are in one package they can be found easier in visually. I do not want to put them together only because of the easier found. So I am searching another evidence but obliviously performance is not the one.

Comment: @Xelian I personally agree with the notion to stick all Controllers together in some web package and have seen a similar practice in several projects, but of course this depends on the overall size and structure of your app.

Comment: @CodeRunner Ok but I suppose that in the future the number of controllers will increase to 40-50.

Comment: @Xelian Sounds like way to many classes for a single package especially based on the assumption that those Controllers are quite diverse functionality-wise.