# Spring4 + Hibernate4 Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am using Spring 4.26 + Hibernate 4.3.

I saw this thread [Are there best practices for (Java) package organisation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226282/are-there-best-practices-for-java-package-organisation) been trying to test if organizing the packes by module/features with spring mvc

But as I am testing this out I can not quite figure out why I am getting this hibernate exception.

[image: Package]

**Edit1:**  I added this screen shot to show my packages.  The odd thing is if I refactor com.app to com.app.controller and change the app-dispatcher-servlet.xml base-package to com.app.controller everything works.... but why?

Stack trace

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1014)
    at com.app.books.BookDao.session(BookDao.java:24)
    at com.app.books.BookDao.getBookList(BookDao.java:31)
    at com.app.IndexController.pagIndex(IndexController.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:832)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I have attached screen shot of the package just in case I missing something[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

I have been checking all of my component-scan base-packages they all seem correct for me

Web.xml

```
<!-- Dispatcher Servlet -->
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>app-dispatcher</display-name>
    <servlet-name>app-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>app-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- Context Listener -->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>
```

app-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.app" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>

    <!-- Resource mapping for css, js, sass files -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/html/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/template/tiles-definitions.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com"></context:component-scan>
    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Spring Hibernate Set up 
         http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html -->

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/unicare_test"></property>
        <property name="username" value="unicare"></property>
        <property name="password" value="unicare"></property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>

        </property>

        <property name="packagesToScan">
                <list>
                    <value>com.app.books</value>

                </list>
            </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="exceptionTranslator"
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor">
    </bean>
```

BookDao

```
@Repository
@Transactional
@Component("bookDao")
public class BookDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    public Session session(){
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    // Get all list of books
    public List<Book> getBookList(){

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Book> returnObj = session().createQuery("from Book").list();

        return returnObj;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This questions is already answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26203446/spring-hibernate-could-not-obtain-transaction-synchronized-session-for-current

Comment: hummm if you look at my code I have all bits... <tx:annotation-driven /> transactionManager, @Repository + @ Transactional